# MongoDB Cluster - Can't access member of shard with credentials

Tags: mongodb, clustering, authentication, users, sharding

I have a Sharded Cluster and I am trying to access a specific member of a replica set within a shard.

When connecting to the mongos it is fine, but when using the same credentials on a member of the replica set I am unable to gain access even though my user has the role of root.

The error is:

> SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on admin from client
>   127.0.0.1:39356 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user root@admin

The mongos are started with:

```
mongos --configdb cfg/mongo-cfg0:27019,mongo-cfg1:27019,mongo-cfg2:27019 --bind_ip_all --keyFile "/etc/mongodb-keyfile"
```

The members of the replica set are started with:

```
mongod --auth --bind_ip_all --shardsvr --replSet a --smallfiles --oplogSize 50  --keyFile "/etc/mongodb-keyfile"
```

When connecting to the mongos I use the following locally:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

When connecting to the memnber of the replica set locally i try and use:

```
mongo --port 27018 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I feel like there is something obvious that I am missing but I can not figure out what, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After looking at some documentation I have come across 'Shard Local Users', but I can't find how to create the user.
[link] https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `mongoS` authentication is done against config servers `admin` database. When you connect directly to replica set, you are authenticating against replica set's `admin` database, where you don't have that `root` user set.

What can you do? Start replica set's (one by one) without --auth parameter (or equivalent config parameter) to maintenance mode, connect that RS with mongo command, create that `root` user (and other needed users). After that you can restart RS with authentication and you can do login.

Answer (score -1):

shard members authentication requires local credentials. As what JJussi has said, you need to create local users on the sharded replica sets.